# Call a method from a method of another class (Nested Class)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question follows on from a previous one I asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770357/best-practices-initializing-class-attributes) from which I tried to follow the advice given by @jonrsharpe

I want to follow the bank accounts of a user that I initiate with the following file

config.yaml

```
banks:
  - name: HSBC
    accounts:
      - distinct_id: abcd1234
        owner:
          name: jason
          mail: jason.musk@gmail.com
        products:
          - name: product1
            currencies:
            - currency: EUR
              total: 1009
            - currency: USD
              total: 809.9
          - name: product2
            currencies:
            - currency: CNY
              total: 47966
            - currency: USD
              total: 9.90
```

I then create a class for each configuration part (Bank, Account, Owner, etc ...). The classes are therefore nested to follow the hierarchy of my configuration file.

main.py

```
import yaml


def load_configurations(path):
    with open(path, "r") as stream:
        try:
            return yaml.safe_load(stream)
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
            print(e)


class Currency:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.currency = kwargs['currency']
        self.total = kwargs['total']


class Product:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.currencies = {}
        for currency in kwargs['currencies']:
            self.add_currency(currency['currency'], currency)

    def add_currency(self, name, currency):
        self.currencies[name] = Currency(**currency)

    def get_currency(self, currency):
        return self.currencies[currency]


class Owner:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs["name"]
        self.mail = kwargs["mail"]


class Account:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.owner = Owner(**kwargs['owner'])

        self.products = {}
        for product in kwargs['products']:
            self.add_product(product['name'], product)

    def add_product(self, name, product):
        self.products[name] = Product(**product)

    def get_product(self, name):
        return self.products[name]

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner


class Bank:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.accounts = {}
        for account in kwargs['accounts']:
            self.add_account(account['distinct_id'], account)

    def add_account(self, name, account):
        self.accounts[name] = Account(**account)

    def get_account(self, distinct_id):
        return self.accounts[distinct_id]


class Configuration:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.banks = {}
        for bank in kwargs['banks']:
            self.add_bank(bank['name'], bank)

    def add_bank(self, name, bank):
        self.banks[name] = Bank(**bank)

    def get_bank(self, name):
        return self.banks[name]


path_configuration = "config.yaml"
config_global = load_configurations(path_configuration)
env = Configuration(**config_global)
```

I now want to be able to query the existing balance for a particular account for a user. I can do this in two ways:

- Through a mapping:

```
result = env.banks['HSBC'].accounts['abcd1234'].products['product1'].currencies['USD'].total
print(result)
```

- Or through the methods:

```
result = env.get_bank('HSBC').get_account('abcd1234').get_product('product1').get_currency('USD').total
print(result)
```

By going through the methods (which is more explicit than by the mapping), I hoped that my IDE (Pycharm) offers me the methods available for each class/object. It does it for my first Configuration() class by offering me the get_bank() method ... But does not do it for the others. How can I fix this?

Comment: IDE might not be smart enough to detect that  `get_bank` will return a `Bank` instance to suggest its methods/attributes. But usually IDE's suggests when you start typing based on string search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated which IDE you're using, so I'll just provide some general advice.

Python is *dynamically typed*, which means a function can return whatever it wants and doesn't have to declare it in advance. Thus, in general, your IDE cannot tell what a function returns without running the function itself, and doing so would mean that computation may or may not terminate.

That being said, you can provide [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to your Python which static analysis tools can use to determine return values. That might look something like

```
from typing import Any, Dict

class Configuration:
    banks: Dict[str, Bank]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.banks = {}
        for bank in kwargs['banks']:
            self.add_bank(bank['name'], bank)

    def add_bank(self, name: str, bank: Bank) -> None:
        self.banks[name] = Bank(**bank)

    def get_bank(self, name: str) -> Bank:
        return self.banks[name]
```

Then, it is *possible* that your IDE will pick up on these signatures. But again, this depends on what editor you're running and how advanced it is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Silvio Mayolo. I will try to follow your advice. I work with Pycharm (I just updated my question to add this information)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer that works perfectly!